# difference between char array and string in cplusplus

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to know the difference between character array and string in c++.

Can any one answer to this??
Please,

Thanks 
Vishnukumar

Comment: I get tons of hits when I search this exact title on Google.

Comment: That question is language-agnostic, this one is specific to C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a class/object, with methods and encapsulated data.

A char array is simply a contiguous block of memory meant to hold chars.

Comment: thank you... in char array we have to specify the size, in string it takes default 4bytes.. am i right? is this a different?

Comment: "in string it takes default 4bytes": I don't know what you mean.

Comment: i m not sure how many bytes of memory string takes. i meant 4bytes of memory.

Comment: It depends how long your string is, but you're getting into a separate question, and stackoverflow is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum, so it would be better for you to search to see if your question has already been answered, or ask a new question yourself.

Comment: when i search while asking question i didnt find duplicate one.. so i came to ask new .. i will mind this.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

(1) `char` array is just a block of `char` type data:
e.g. `char c[100];` // 100 continuous bytes are allotted to `c`

(2a) By `string`, if you mean `char` string then, it's little similar to array but it's allocated in the readonly segment of the memory and should be assigned to a `const char*`:
e.g. `const char *p = "hello";` // "hello" resides in continuous character buffer

[note: `char c[] = "hello";` belongs to category (1) and not to (2a)]

(2b) By `string` if yo umean `std::string` then, it's a standard library class from header  and you may want to refer its documentation or search on [web](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)